# Execution failed for task ':react-native:ReactAndroid:hermes-engine:configureBuildForHermes'

Tags: javascript, react-native

I encountered an error while attempting to build and install the app using the 'yarn android' command. The error message and relevant details are as follows:

I am new to open souce like I am trying to do open source

I cloned Rocket.Chat.ReactNative  https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat.ReactNative.git
then did yarn install
and then yarn andoid and encountered this error

-----------------------------------*******************************************************------------------------------------------------------

Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installExperimentalPlayDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:42 (cmake_policy):
The OLD behavior for policy CMP0026 will be removed from a future version
of CMake.

The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:64 (project):
Running

'nmake' '-?'

failed with:

The system cannot find the file specified

CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native:ReactAndroid:hermes-engine:configureBuildForHermes'.

> Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 29m 47s

```
at makeError (C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\Open Source Projects\Rocket.Chat.ReactNative\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\Open Source Projects\Rocket.Chat.ReactNative\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\Open Source Projects\Rocket.Chat.ReactNative\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:82:7s:82:7)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\Open Source Projects\Rocket.Chat.ReactNative\ntive\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:108:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

-----------------------------------*******************************************************------------------------------------------------------

I have ensured that I have the Android development environment set up following the instructions provided in the React Native documentation. However, the build process encountered the following issues:

Deprecation warning related to policy CMP0026 in CMakeLists.txt.
CMake errors related to 'nmake' and missing compiler settings (CMAKE_C_COMPILER and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER).
Failure during the task ':react-native:ReactAndroid:hermes-engine:configureBuildForHermes' with a non-zero exit value.
I have tried running the command with additional options such as '--stacktrace', '--info', and '--debug', but the error persists.

I would appreciate any assistance in resolving this build error and successfully installing the app. Thank you for your help.

Operating system: 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Node.js version: v18.16.0
Yarn version: 1.22.19
React Native version: 0.71.7

I tried downloading latest version of cmake downloaded gcc g++ tried deleting node_modules and reinstalling the project